# What exactly std::function() does when stored in a container?

Tags: c++, std-function, stdbind

What exactly `std::function` constructor does when stored in a container ?

In this test codes:

```
struct A {
    int sn;
    A() = delete;
    A(int v) : sn(v) { cout << "A::init(" << sn << ')' << endl; }
    A(const A& a) : sn(a.sn+1) { cout << "A::copy(" << sn << ')' << endl; }
    A(A&& a) : sn(a.sn+1) { cout << "A::move(" << sn << ')' << endl; }
    ~A() { cout << "A::delete(" << sn << ')' << endl; }
};

void func(int a, A &b) {
    cout << "func2:" << a << ',' << b.sn << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::function<void(void)>> fv;
    A a(1);
    cout << "call bind()" << endl;
    fv.emplace_back(std::bind(func,1,a));
    fv.front()();
    cout << "end of local scope" << endl;
}
```

I declare the move and copy constructors of `class A` to accumulate a sequence number, so that I can track it as the Nth created instance. The result is:

```
A::init(1)
call bind()
A::copy(2)
A::move(3)
A::move(4)
A::delete(3)
A::delete(2)
func2:1,4
end of local scope
A::delete(1)
A::delete(4)
```

First an instance `a(1)` is created in `main()` local scope, then it's copied as a new instance `a(2)` when calling `std::bind()`, then moved again into `std::function` dynamically allocated memory (or its internal memory footage?) to hold a copy of `std::bind()` instance, so we have the 3rd instances of `A` held by `std::function` instance.

So far it's understandable, but why is there another move construction ? And why the 3rd instance is destructed before the 2nd instance, which is supposed to be cleared when `std::bind()` returns ?

If I rewrite the `main()` function as:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    A a(1);
    cout << "call bind()" << endl;
    std::function<void(void)> f(std::bind(func,1,a));
    f();
    cout << "end of local scope" << endl;
}
```

then the result would be:

```
A::init(1)
call bind()
A::copy(2)
A::move(3)
A::delete(2)
func2:1,3
end of local scope
A::delete(3)
A::delete(1)
```

There is no second move construction and everything looks reasonable.

What exactly happened when calling `emplace_back()` to create `std::function` instance in this case ?

Comment: It's not the vector, nor `std::function`. It's `std::bind`. It's semantics are mostly implementation defined, and its parameters are likely to be juggled around, a bit, before they settle down in their resting place... A lazy afternoon, with a couple of hours to spare, should be enough to gingerly step through, in your debugger, through everything that happens here and determine the reason and the cause for every move or copy.

Comment: You might consider it more weird if you change `emplace_back` to `push_back`. In my quick tests, the second move was omitted, making `push_back` look more efficient than `emplace_back` in this case.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik No, it is `std::function`/`emplace_back`. More specifically, it's perfect forwarding showing the fact that it's not actually perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First an instance `a(1)` is created in `main()` local scope, then it's copied as a new instance `a(2)` when calling `std::bind()`, then moved again into `std::function` dynamically allocated memory

You're missing a step: `std::function`'s constructor takes by-value

```
template<typename F>
std::function<void(void)>::function(F f);
```

`emplace_back` is forwarding the `std::bind`-wrapper containing `a(2)` as an rvalue, yes, but this constructor only accepts by value, not by rvalue reference, so the `a(2)` gets moved and becomes `a(3)` just to initialize the parameter of the constructor. *Then* the constructor moves that value out into dynamic storage.

```
int main() {
    A a(1); // A::init(1)
    // this is the temporary that gets materialized in main's scope for the call to emplace_back
    auto wrapper = std::bind(func, 1, a); // A::copy(2);
    // emplace_back receives (a reference to) the temporary as an rvalue, and so it passes std::function's constructor a reference to the same object, also as an rvalue
    // but std::function's constructor only takes values...
    std::function<void(void)> f(std::move(wrapper));
    // initializing the parameter of constructor (in main/emplace_back's context): A::move(3)
    // constructor then initializes dynamically allocated object: A::move(4)
    // constructor destroys parameter object: A::delete(3)
    // f gets destroyed, takes dynamically allocated object with it: A::delete(4)
    // wrapper (the temporary) gets destroyed (originally at the ; after emplace_back): A::delete(2)
    // a gets destroyed: A::delete(1);
}
// Note: the reason A::delete(4) comes before A::delete(1) in my version but not yours is that your A(4) lives inside fv, which is created at the top of main and thus is the last thing destroyed, but mine lives inside f, which is created at the end and is the first thing destroyed
```

The difference in your simplification is that you're not materializing the result of `std::bind` as a temporary. Basically, `emplace_back` requires that the arguments already be fully constructed (as does any function call). So you have to execute the `std::bind` (and the copy inside it) just to call `emplace_back`, and *then* `emplace_back` moves that object to the constructor parameter. But, when you pass the `std::bind` prvalue directly to the `std::function` constructor, the constructor parameter object is directly constructed by setting `std::bind`'s result object to the parameter object during its execution.

Another way to say it: `std::function`'s constructor must be called with a newly created object. When using `emplace_back`, the intervening function "forgets" the `std::bind`-call was a newly constructed object, so a new object is constructed by doing an "extraneous" move. When you remove `emplace_back`, then the fact that the `std::bind` object is newly constructed is not forgotten and the move is elided.

Another another way to say it: "perfect" forwarding as claimed by `emplace_back` is actually not perfect; such a thing isn't possible (the user code must be modified). "Perfect" forwarding forwards lvalues as lvalues, but collapses both xvalues and prvalues as xvalues (by requiring prvalues be materialized before the function is even called). Calling `std::function`'s constructor with an xvalue causes two moves, but calling with a prvalue causes one. Your second version passes a prvalue to the constructor, but the original passes an xvalue, so they have different behavior.

You can get the desired result with a wrapper functor:

```
template<typename F>
struct initializer {
    F f;
    operator decltype(f())() && {
        return std::move(f)();
    }
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::function<void(void)>> fv;
    A a(1);
    cout << "call bind()" << endl;
    fv.emplace_back(
        initializer{[&]() -> std::function<void(void)> {
            return std::bind(func, 1, a);
        }});
    fv.front()();
    cout << "end of local scope" << endl;
}
```

This puts the call to `std::bind` directly under the call to `std::function`'s constructor (which is in the `return`), so the prvalue directly initializes the constructor parameter with no intervening move. The `std::function` is also constructed directly in the "empty" space in the vector, with no further moving (that's what `emplace_back` does, after all).

Comment: OK, so emplace_back will force creating a new instance from ```std::bind()``` returned rvalue, then ```std::move()``` that new instance to ```std::function``` constructor, only because the constructor only accept pass-by-value, not by-reference, is that correct ? If I use ```push_back()``` instead, a new ```std::function()``` will first created with temporary ```A::move(3)```, but then another ```std::function()``` will be created inside dynamic memory of ```std::vector``` using ```std::function(function &&)``` move constructor, so I won't see A::move(4) but there is still a move construction.